# Automatically setting parent id when creating item from list part in Business Central/AL

Tags: customization, dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

I am quite new to building extensions with AL for Business Central. I am trying to setup an extension for a school application. The tables I have built work, and they follow this data model:

```
School - Course - Lecture
  |     /
Teacher
```

Inside the `Card` for `School`, I am showing a list part for `Course`.  It correctly shows all courses of a given school. So far so good. But now, whenever I create a `Course` from this view, I have to remember to set the `SchoolId` manually, but I would like to do this automatically because we already know which `School` we are in.

The `Course` table looks like this:

```
table 50110 Course
{
    DataClassification = ToBeClassified;
    DrillDownPageId = "Course List";
    LookupPageId = "Course List";


    fields
    {
        field(1; "No."; Code[20])
        ...
        field(5; "SchoolId"; Code[20])
        {
            DataClassification = ToBeClassified;
            TableRelation = School."No.";
        }
    }

    keys
    {
        key(PK; "No.")
        {
            Clustered = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The `Course` list part explicitly does not contain the `SchoolId`, as we would expect this to be managed automatically:

```
page 50118 "Course List Part"
{
    PageType = ListPart;
    UsageCategory = None;
    SourceTable = Course;
    CardPageId = "Course Card";
    // InsertAllowed = false;

    layout
    {
        area(Content)
        {
            repeater(GroupName)
            {
                field("No."; "No.") { ApplicationArea = All; }
                field(Name; Name) { ApplicationArea = All; }
                field(CourseOwnerId; CourseOwnerId) { ApplicationArea = All; }
                // field(SchoolId; SchoolId) { ApplicationArea = All; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `School` card invokes the `Course list part` on the appropriate view:

```
page 50117 "School Card"
{
    PageType = Card;
    UsageCategory = None;
    SourceTable = School;

    layout
    {
        area(Content)
        {
            group(General)
            {
                field("No."; "No.")
                {
                    ApplicationArea = All;

                }
                field(Name; Name)
                {
                    ApplicationArea = All;

                }
            }
            group("Extras 1")
            {
                part("Courses"; "Course List Part")
                {
                    ApplicationArea = All;
                    SubPageLink = SchoolId = field("No.");
                    UpdatePropagation = Both;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And of course, the `School` table, where the `No.` property is set as the primary key:

```
table 50113 School
{
    DataClassification = ToBeClassified;
    DrillDownPageId = "School List";
    LookupPageId = "School List";

    fields
    {
        field(1; "No."; Code[20])
        {
            DataClassification = ToBeClassified;
        }
        ...
    }

    keys
    {
        key(PK; "No.")
        {
            Clustered = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Still, no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the 'Course' page as to the 'School page', the sub-page link will automatically handle that part of the relationship for you;  when you insert a new record it will automatically populate No. with 'SchoolId'.

e.g. this is how it works on the Sales Order page.

```
 part(SalesLines; "Sales Order Subform")
            {
                ApplicationArea = Basic, Suite;
                Editable = DynamicEditable;
                Enabled = "Sell-to Customer No." <> '';
                SubPageLink = "Document No." = FIELD("No.");
                UpdatePropagation = Both;
            }
```

You must also define a table relation from the 'Child' table to the 'Parent' table, e.g.

```
table 50121 child
{ 
    fields
    {
        field(1; ParentID; Integer)
        {          
            TableRelation = Parent.ID;
```

The field you're linking on must be a primary key of the Child table, i.e. **'SchoolID' must be in the primary key of 'course' in your code.**

Comment: Thanks, I just tried, but unfortunately I did not manage to get your code to working. The SubPageLink alone does not take care of the update, and `No.` is definitely in the primary key of `Course` in my example.

I have neither `Enabled`, nor `Editable`, but I cannot imagine why they would need to be there to implement this behaviour (and I don't know why (still beginner), but `DynamicEditable` does not compile).

Any idea what else I could try?

Comment: Just tried it out myself, and realised we both missed something else, evidently a tablerelation needs to be defined from the child table's field too,  makes sense I guess,  had you done that?  Updated answer.

Comment: Curiouser and curiouser, because indeed I would expect this to work like you describe. I am updating my original question with more code. It looks aligned to what you suggest as far as my inexperienced eyes can see...

Comment: I tried adding the `TableRelation = Parent.Id`, because it was `TableRelation = Parent`, but still: no luck.

Comment: Ahha, I think schoolid must be part of the primary key of the courses table.

Comment: YES! It works!!! Weird and a bit unexpected/obscure, but certainly not absurd.

Interesting to note, is that after adding the SchoolId to the PK of the Course table, the Course list part is still editable, but to add an item I now have to click on Actions -> New, instead of just getting an extra empty line where I can start typing. When Choosing Actions -> New, then I get the SchoolId prefilled.

Any idea what this means, or even where this behaviour would be documented?